# Procesar fragmentos de QueryBuilder con chunk()

Tags: laravel, eloquent, querybuilder

tengo un método de una clase que extiendo de ELOQUENT que tiene que procesar colecciones muy grandes del orden de mas de 800 000 items y me he dado cuenta que eventualmente causa algunas dificultades en el servicio, por lo que decidí según consejos de la propia documentación de Laravel, usar el método chunk() desde QueryBuilder.
El proceso es leer las entradas existentes en cierto rango de fechas y luego calcular promedios en subdivisiones de tiempo de toda la colección, para mostrar en una gráfica de comportamientos.
El problema es que el método chunk() procesa perfectamente cada fragmento calculando los promedios de cada segmento de entradas pero no logro que devuelva dichos promedios, los puedo imprimir desde un "echo" pero como por defecto hace un ciclo iterando entre cada fragmento de la colección, al final sólo me devuelve un "true" y no un Array de promedios por fecha, que es lo deseado.
Este es el código que tengo hasta ahora.

```
public static function gghh($campo, $marca = [], $corte=5000)
{
    $ini = isset($marca["ini"]) ? $marca["ini"] : Carbon::now()->subDay()->format('Y-m-d');
    $fin = isset($marca["fin"]) ? $marca["fin"] : Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');

    return self::whereBetween("fecha", [$ini, $fin])->chunk($corte,function ($regs) use ($campo){

        //echo $regs->avg($campo)."<br />";
        //echo $regs->first()->fecha."<br />";
    
        if(!isset($trozos))
        {
           $trozos = [];
        }
        
        array_push($trozos, ["dato" => $regs->avg($campo), "fecha" => $regs->first()->fecha]);

        return $trozos
    });
}
```

Se que el proceso se realiza correctamente porque si quito los comentarios a los dos "echo" los valores se muestran correctamente, pero necesito que estos mismos valores me sean devueltos para un proceso posterior.
Tal cual está ahora mostrado, el método sólo devuelve un valor boleano (TRUE)
¿Alguna idea para obtener algo como el Array que sigue?

```
[
  ["dato"=>145.58, "fecha"=>"2020-08-12"],
  ["dato"=>128.89, "fecha"=>"2020-09-12"],
  ["dato"=>132.14, "fecha"=>"2020-10-12"],
  ["dato"=>136.62, "fecha"=>"2020-11-12"],
  ...
]
```

Comment: Justamente eso es lo que estoy tratando de hacer ... bajo las dos líneas comentadas en el código hay un array_push que evalua si la variable a devolver existe .. si existe le inyecta un nuevo valor y si no existe la crea añadiendo su primer indice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es un problema de scope. Si `$trozos` no existe y lo declaras dentro del bucle, no existe fuera de éste, ni en el bucle siguiente. El método `chunk` no es un `map` del que puedas retornar, sino sólo un `each` en cómodas cuotas.

El único efecto que tiene `return $trozos` es que si en alguna iteración esta variable es falsy se asume que no quieres seguir procesando los lotes.

Yo probaría:

```
  $trozos = [];

  return self::whereBetween("fecha", [$ini, $fin])
      ->chunk($corte, function ($regs) use ($campo, &$trozos){
      
       $trozos[] = [
           "dato" => $regs->avg($campo), 
           "fecha" => $regs->first()->fecha
       ]);
  });
```

Fíjate que le paso `$trozos` por referencia, dado que si lo paso como valor lo esperable sería no afectar su valor en el scope superior.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, realmente me ayudó mucho tu comentario, porque todo el tiempo estuve esperando un comportamiento similar al de map() y obviamente jamás llegaban los valores, en la solución final que logré, ni siquiera necesito implementar un return en este punto, pues ciertamente lo único que podría devolver es un valor boleano, en cambio el valor de la variable referenciada "$trozos" se rescata al final limpiamente, Gracias nuevamente, Llevaba todo un día en el asunto !